# WPF - C# - How do I use Bitblit method to capture a custom shape of a bitmap?

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, bit, capture

I am working with WPF, C#. I would like to use BitBlit to capture the part of an image that over imposes another image. Since the two images can be rotated, the shape of the capture may not be a rectangle. 
Unfortunately the Bitblit class doesn't seem to be accepting else but a rectangle.

```
public static bool BitBlt(
    IntPtr hDC,
    int x,
    int y,
    int nWidth,
    int nHeight,
    IntPtr hSrcDC,
    int xSrc,
    int ySrc,
    int dwRop
)
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution?
Btw i dont have to use BitBlit, it just seems to me the best way to go
(FYI, I am not an experienced programmer)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjMFj.png)

Comment: `BitBlt` is a low-level, very fast, image copy using direct memory access. As such, it is restricted to rectangular areas.  To copy just that area, I would use `BitBlt` to capture a rectangular area large enough to encompass the entire intersection, then draw it to a new surface using a clip path defined by the intersection of the 2 original shapes.

Comment: Thank you so much! You definetly put me on the right track :) really appreciated! Cant seem to be able to vote up for your help Oo